# Building stairs in congested area

Tags: stairs

I want to build stairs in rectangular area of 6 feet by 9 feet to reach ceiling which is 8 feet high above ground floor. Is it possible build such stairs?

If yes, then what would be height of steps? I want to mention that step size of stairs should be between 6 to 7 inch.

Comment: Sounds like you need an architect.

Comment: does the 6' x 9' area include the required landings? if so, I suspect a spiral staircase is in your future.

Comment: @cornwalker....yes, can not we do without spiral?

Comment: If the ceiling is 8" above the floor, you might need to take account of the ceiling thickness as well it's likely to be more than the height of one step.

Comment: What does "possible" mean? What codes apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8' in 6" steps is 16 steps. If the tread is around 10" as is common, that's a little over 13'. If you divide the space in half to have 3' wide steps, with a half landing the same width, you only have 12' to play with suggesting that you'd need steps going round the end rather than a half landing. That's not common on a 180 degree bend (but is on a 90 degree bend).

However, 6" risers are rather shallow. Going just over the 7" risers you mention would allow you to make the climb in 14 steps  which would work with a half landing the same wish as the steps.

There may be regulations to consider, and obviously you have to make an allowance on the width for banisters, but it should be possible for a competent builder to design something into the space.

Answer (score 1):

nope - cannot be done with the stipulation you have provided.  even if you go to the maximum allowable height for rise, 7.875 inches, there is no way to fit the required number of steps in the space you have allotted.  you need more space in one way or the other, or you have to accept the fact that you need to make non-compliant steps (it can be done with 8.75 inch high steps)